# MultiThreading issue on i7 processor with windows8 os

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows-8, multicore

I was running an application with 2 threads. One thread saving images grabs from camera and another thread processing that images, the issue here is, Processing thread stops(stalled or blocked can't able to get it) in the middle of processing after some(random at each time of running) hours, but it works fine on i3 with windows7 and also in dual core processor with windowsXp. There is no critical section or lock in both threads. Please help me to solve this issue.

Code from thread2:

```
fn_Waitforfiles(); // while loop waits until the 4 images saved in watch folder if not it will return at count of 50
  CString strLog = "";
  strLog.Format("Entering Skipping..");
  for(int d = 1; d <= m_iInterLeave; d++)
  {
   m_ifileCount++;
   m_strcurFilePath.Format("%s\\%lu.jpeg", m_strToProcessDir, m_ifileCount);
   if(PathFileExists(m_strcurFilePath))
    ::DeleteFile(m_strcurFilePath);
   else
   {
    m_ifileCount--;
    m_strcurFilePath.Format("%s\\%lu.jpeg", m_strToProcessDir, m_ifileCount);
   }
   if(d == m_iInterLeave)
   {
    m_ifileCount++;
    m_strcurFilePath.Format("%s\\%lu.jpeg", m_strToProcessDir, m_ifileCount);   
   }
  }
  strLog = "";
  strLog.Format("Skipped %d images on Interleaving..", m_iInterLeave);
  MSSLOGGER::WriteLog(_T(strLog));
```

After writing log "Enter Skipping.." thread2 was no more running

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The experts are better able to help you if you can share your code (preferable a minimal example). Also, elaborate on what you have done to debug the issue.  If the processing is stuck on one thread, have you tried attaching a debugger to ascertain what the issue is? (Or any other debugging)?

Comment: The way the project runs is,
Thread1:
Grab images from camera
Save the images in a path
//continues until stop grabing
Thread2:
Detect motion in the saved images
skipped two images if motion not detected
//continues until there is no more images. 
from the log Thread2 stops processing we cannot able to debug as it happens in client machine which we cannot have access

Comment: You will need to show code if we're going to help you because your explanation of the process has too many holes. For example, you say there are no locks, so how are the images being transferred between the threads? When you say there are 2 threads, are there genuinely only 2 threads that never finish, or are you spinning up a new thread regularly and assuming that the previous thread has shut down. Showing us code will probably answer these questions and the others that will undoubtedly come up.

Comment: The code contains lot of functions which part i would give you since i dont know the exact function in which the problem causes. i used opencv cvloadimage for saving and processing images(i didnt use lock here), thread1 stops when the user wants to stop grabbing thread2 will run forever watching images in a folder. no new threads are created, genuinely 2 threads only.

Answer (score 1):

The clue is probably in "watching images in folder".  That sounds like you rely on file change notifications, and those can be missed (more accurately, a number of them may be collapsed into one single summary notification).

Comment: i always saving images in unsigned long starts from 1; and watching images by that number; both threads have separate variable to maintain file count also thread1 will always 3 file count ahead of thread2

Comment: @venki: I don't understand what you mean. Sure, you can predict the _name_ of the new file, but not _when_ it appears.

Comment: I will wait until that file appears.

Comment: @venki: but HOW? How do you wait? It sounds like your program waits forever, so waiting is definitely a suspicious activity.